how to Cache Paging 3 Data in List?
Can i cache paging data in list from Flow Map or what is correct approach to cache data in list
I am working on tree data structure for this i need to cache list
so i'm trying to cache data from flow, so is it right approach ?
      val list = SnapShotList<Comment>()


    fun  getYoutubeComments() = Pager(
    config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 10),
    pagingSourceFactory = {
        RemotePagingSource(
               youtubeClient = youtubeClient
        )
    }

).flow.map {paggingData ->

   paggingData.map {
        list.add(it )

       it
    }


}


Part of the point behind paging is that you may not have memory for everything that you are trying to load.
